# Assembly (Intel syntax + NASM) Error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels

Tags: assembly, nasm, 32-bit, intel-syntax

I am quite new regarding the assembly and I am trying to work with a program. So whenever I try to compile it, I get the error for the line, as listed under the comments in the code.

**I am wondering if anyone has any ideas why NASM detects this errors when I am defining some things for the rest of the assembly code?**

Maybe it has to do something with how the main is defined?

P.S. I listed just the first part of the code, since the program is quite long.

Thank you for the help

```
.xlist               ;attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
include  stdlib.a     ;  parser: instruction expected
includelib stdlib.lib    ; parser: instruction expected
.list
.286

dseg            segment para public 'data' 
;  Unknown section attribute 'public' ignored on declaration of section `para'
h               word    ?
i               word    ?

cseg            segment para public 'code'
                assume  cs:cseg, ds:dseg

Main
```

Comment: Rolled back your edit because the later error messages are useful, too.  People searching on those errors might find this question, which would be useful.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh sorry, I thought they are useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NASM a label starting with dot is called a local label. It is appended to the last global label, for example,

```
L:
.l2: ; it is really L.l2
```

So you cannot have a local label before any global ones

Comment: This is the correct answer and it removes all the local label errors. Thank you.

Comment: The correct answer is that your source file is not in nasm syntax at all. Looks more like masm or tasm.

Comment: @Jester Like I said, I am quite new to assembly. So I will look into that. May I ask because of what do you think it's in masm or tasm syntax?

Comment: Because of all the directives used. For example, [NASM Doesn't ASSUME](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.4)

Answer (score 2):

That's not NASM code at all.  As @Jester says, it's probably TASM or MASM.

[NASM doesn't `ASSUME`](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.4), so you can be 100% sure this is not NASM code.

---

It's definitely not Linux code, either.  Note the `.286` directive.  That means it will be 16-bit code.  Even if you convert the syntax to NASM, the resulting binary will not do anything useful on your Linux system.

(This question doesn't mention Linux, but [the followup does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41041009/parser-instruction-expected-error-while-compiling-intel-assembly-with-nasm)).

Comment: So instead of compiling it with:     nasm -f elf codeasm.asm -o codeasm.o  
I should compile it for 16 bits and on Windows?

Comment: @io16: No, you should delete it and find something modern to look at.  Learning DOS system calls and 16-bit segmented memory is something you could do later, but is just a distraction for now.  Pick one system to learn asm for, e.g. x86-64 Linux.  Once you're comfortable, start learning how other systems are different.