# Parser: Instruction expected Error while compiling Intel assembly with NASM

Tags: assembly, debian, nasm, intel-syntax

**Can anyone tell me why are these errors happening?** I am quite new to the assembly and I have some problems compiling the file.

I tried compiling it in NASM,with following code in Debian:

```
nasm -f elf codeasm.asm -o codeasm.o
```

and I get the following errors:

```
codeasm.asm:2: error: parser: instruction expected
codeasm.asm:3: error: parser: instruction expected
codeasm.asm:5: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
codeasm.asm:6: warning: Unknown section attribute 'public' ignored on  declaration of section `para'
codeasm.asm:6: warning: Unknown section attribute ''data'' ignored on declaration of section `para'    
codeasm.asm:10: error: parser: instruction expected
codeasm.asm:11: error: parser: instruction expected
codeasm.asm:12: error: parser: instruction expected
codeasm.asm:13: error: parser: instruction expected
codeasm.asm:14: error: parser: instruction expected
codeasm.asm:15: error: parser: instruction expected
codeasm.asm:16: error: parser: instruction expected
codeasm.asm:20: error: parser: instruction expected
codeasm.asm:21: error: parser: instruction expected
codeasm.asm:23: error: symbol `dseg' redefined
codeasm.asm:23: error: parser: instruction expected
codeasm.asm:28: warning: Unknown section attribute 'public' ignored on declaration of section `para'
codeasm.asm:28: warning: Unknown section attribute ''indata'' ignored on declaration of section `para'
```

For the following code in assembly Intel syntax (Just the first couple of lines):

```
                    xlist
            include         stdlib.a
            includelib      stdlib.lib
            list
            286
dseg            segment para public 'data'

h               word    ?
i               word    ?
j               word    ?
k               word    ?
l               word    ?
sum             word    ?
iterations      word    ?

InName          byte    "file1.raw",0
OutName         byte    "file2.raw",0

dseg            ends

InSeg           segment para public 'indata'

DataIn          byte    251 dup (256 dup (?))

InSeg           ends

OutSeg          segment para public 'outdata'

DataOut         byte    251 dup (256 dup (?))

OutSeg          ends
```

I was told that this code is working properly.

Comment: That's not nasm syntax code. Looks more like masm or tasm.

Comment: While all three (masm, tasm and nasm) do follow Intel syntax (with small differences), that does not mean the source can be compiled by other assembler easily. The short snippet you posted is full of assembler *directives*, which are not "instructions" of CPU, but provide vital information for Assembler, how the machine code should be build. While TASM does try to emulate MASM up to some extent, NASM is completely different and only very few directives would work, for example `DB/DW/DD` would, but your snippet does use modern `word` instead of more common `DW` from earlier MASM/TASM.

Comment: Also, chances are the code itself isn't for linux either.

Comment: `286` is a dead giveaway that it's not Linux.

Comment: Just like your last question [this is not NASM code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995115/assembly-intel-syntax-nasm-error-attempt-to-define-a-local-label-before-any#comment69199237_40995216), and has the same kinds of directives as the one you asked about last time.

Comment: Haha didn't realize it was the same OP. I even posted the same comment LOL

Comment: @PeterCordes and Jester in the last post you said that you aren't completly sure if this is for NASM, so I wanted to post more of the code, so that you guys could say for sure. Thank you very much.  I will try it on windows with MASM and if you want,  I can keep you posted how it will go

Comment: @Ped7g I will try it with windows and MASM and will keep you posted on how it will go.

Comment: I was totally sure it wasn't nasm. I even quoted the manual for you. I am just not sure what it is :)

Comment: @io16: Find a tutorial for the platform you *do* want to learn.  Throwing random examples for other OSes at NASM is just going to result in having a Bad Time, and being really confused about *why* things don't work.  Especially if it's 16-bit `286` code.

Comment: @Jester: I went looking for that other question to close this as a dup!  I thought "oh, here's another person throwing TASM or MASM code at NASM", and was thinking that one of the answers there had actually said that.  Unfortunately not; the answer just addressed the .label first error, not the bigger problem.

Comment: @Jester: fixed now; added the real answer to the other question.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for the answer on the other question, you can also post it here, since it's probably the correct one for this also.

Comment: @Jester Now I will try compiling it on Windows with 16-bits and I will inform you and Peter how it will go.

Comment: @io16: I marked this as a duplicate of the other one.  That's what we do on SO instead of re-posting copies information.

Comment: @PeterCordes First I was told that I must do some changes to this code in particular, but now my teacher has informed me, that this code is really old and we should only use it as an example. So if I had this knowledge before, I wouldn't even ask this... But still thank you for help again.

Comment: It's not always a bad thing to ask a duplicate question.  Sometimes you can only tell if you already know the answer.  Closing as a duplicate isn't saying it shouldn't have been asked in the first place.  (Although in this case, if you'd read and understood all the comments on your previous question, you wouldn't have had to ask this.)

Comment: @PeterCordes A man can only admit when he was wrong. :)